# How to map the data that are fetched from Api in angular

Tags: angular

I have fetched the author's names along with their posts from api. It is first showing the list of all author;s names , after that it is showing the list of all posts. but i want that it show the author's name with their respective posts. I had tried several ways but it won't worked.Please help me.
Here is my code

data.service.ts

```
       constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

       getuserdetails(){
           return this.http.get<any> 
          ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .pipe(map(item => {
           return item;
          }));
         }

      getposts() {
            return this.http.get<any> 
           ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
           .pipe(map(user => {
           return user;
         }));
         }
```

home.component.ts

```
      dataItem:any = {} 
      post:any = {} 

     constructor(private data: DataService) {

          this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
          this.dataItem=item;
        });

          this.data.getposts().subscribe(element=>{
          this.post=element;
       });

    }
```

home.component.html

```
   <div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>0">

      <div *ngFor='let x of dataItem'>
         {{x.name}}
      </div>

      <div *ngFor='let y of post'>
          {{y.body}} 
      </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for both observables to finish and then execute your logic

```
 constructor(private data: DataService) {
         zip(this.data.getuserdetails(),this.data.getposts()).subscribe((results)=> 
          {
             this.dataItem = results[0];
             this.post = results[1];
          });

        });


       });
```

Comment: getting Error- Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, any, any]>>

Comment: import { zip } from 'rxjs';
write this up to file

Comment: i have already written import { zip } from 'rxjs'  but still getting the error

Comment: try remove this.data.getuserdetails() and leave the second one are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes sir. same error again. Sir can u please copy paste my code in your software and try to execute it. it will be really helpful.

Comment: it works for me can you show me the imports you are using at the top of the file?

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { userInfo } from 'os';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

Comment: constructor(private data: DataService) {
  this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
    console.log(item);
    this.dataItem=item;
});
this.data.getposts().subscribe(element=>{
  console.log(element);
  this.post=element;
});
    zip(this.data.getuserdetails(),this.data.getposts()).subscribe((results)=> 
          {
             this.dataItem = results[0];
             this.post = results[1];
          });

        
}

Comment: import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators' correct this with import { zip } from 'rxjs'

Comment: "../../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'zip'. TypeError: rxjs_1.zip is not a function. These are errors i am getting now

Comment: try to copy this it works for me which "rxjs" version are you using?

Comment: try this import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip'

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, any, any]>>' . TypeError: operators_1.zip(...).subscribe is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating custom filter pipe

```
<div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>0">

    <div *ngFor='let x of dataItem'>
    {{x.name}}
        <div *ngIf="post && post.length">
            <div *ngFor="let y of post | filter : x.id">
                {{y.body}} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], userId: any): any[] {
        if(!items) return [];
        if(!userId) return items;
        return items.filter( it => it.userId == userId);
    }
}
```

Also you must import this filter pipe in some module and add it in declarations: [] and exports: []

Comment: Sure pawan. i am replying you within few minutes

Comment: getting error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @Ronit: try filter : x.id

Comment: Thanks bro I got the output. but in console , ERROR TypeError: items.filter is not a function

Comment: @Ronit: Just need to add  *ngIf="post && post.length", I have updated the post

Comment: again getting same error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.